# Long text translation

Tags: internationalization, translation, symfony5

I started with Symfony5 couple days ago and I am trying out symfony/translation package. My problem is I am using two languages(EN as default and PL) and want to translate long block of text with HTML markups in twig template:

```
<h1>Very long text</h1>
<p>With very long paragraphs and markups</p>
```

I store translations in messages.pl.yaml file. For single words or short sentences just basic functionality with {%trans}{%endtrans} was sufficient but have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: It's worth storing translated content, but mark-up wil rapidly become a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to have a separate translatable block per block-level tag, but it quickly became unreadable:

```
<h1>{% trans %}Very long text{% endtrans %}</h1>
<p>{% trans %}With very long paragraphs and markups{% endtrans %}</p>
<p>{% trans with {'%url%': homepage_url_variable} %}With very long paragraphs <a href="%url%">links</a>{% endtrans %}</p>
<p>{% trans %}With very long paragraphs and <i class="fas fa-language"></i> icons{% endtrans %}</p>
```

So I'd suggest using translation keys instead:

```
twig template
  <h1>{{ 'very_long_text'|trans }}</h1>
  <p>{{ 'very_long_text_with_p_and_markups'|trans }}</p>
  <p>{{ 'very_long_text_with_p_and_links'|trans({'%url%': homepage_url_variable})|raw }}</p>
  <p>{{ 'very_long_text_with_p_and_icons'|trans|raw }}</p>

messages.en.yaml file:
  very_long_text: Very long text
  very_long_text_with_p_and_markups: With very long paragraphs and markups
  very_long_text_with_p_and_links: With very long paragraphs <a href="%url%">links</a>
  very_long_text_with_p_and_icons: With very long paragraphs and <i class="fas fa-language"></i> icons
```

The drawback is that UI copywriters and translators won't be able to change the layout.